# linux - sed loop through a list of lines in a file

Tags: linux, loops, sed

I am having some trouble looping through a list of lines in File A and using each line to find a match in File B and then to print out multiple lines in File B.

This is how File A looks like

Nitab4.5_0000062g0520.1

Nitab4.5_0000436g0070.1

Nitab4.5_0000375g0110.1

This is how File B looks like

> Nitab4.5_0000062g0520.1 Zinc finger, CCHC-type, Fibronectin-binding A, N-terminal, Domain of unknown function DUF814, Protein of unknown function DUF3441
>   MVKVRMNTADVAAEVKCLRRLIGMRCSNVYDLSPKTYVFKLMNSSGVTESGESEKVLLLM
>   ESGVRLHTTDYLRDKSNTPSGFTLKLRKHIRTRRLEDVRQLGYDRIVLFQFGLGANAHYV
>   ILELYAQGNILLTDSDFMVMTLLRSHRDDDKGLAIMSRHRYPVEICRVFKRTTTEKLQAA
>   LMSSAETDKNEGVEDNEQGNDGSDALQQKQGNRKNIKATDSTKKMIDGVRAKSPTLKVVL
>   GEALGYGPALSEHIILDAGLVPNAKIGKGFELEGEMLHSLIEAVKQFEDWLEDVILGEKV
>   PEGYILMQQKALSKKDSSMCNNGASEKMYDEFCPLLLNQFKSRDFMKFEAFNAALDEFYS
>   KIESQRSEQQQKAKESTAMQKLNKIRTDQENRVVTLKQEVEHCIKTAELIEYNLEDVDAA
>   ILAVRVALANGMSWEDLARMVKEEKRSGNPVAGLIDKLHLERNCMTLLLSNNLDEMDDDE
>   KTQPVDKVEVDLALSAHANARRWYEMKKRQESKQEKTVTAHEKAFKAAERKTRLQLSQEK
>   TVAVISHMRKVHWFEKFNWFVSSENYLVISGRDAQQNEMIVKRYMSKGDLYVHAELHGAS
>   STVIKNHKPEMPIPPLTLNQAGCFTVCQSQAWDSKIVTSAWWVYPNQVSKTAPTGEYLTV
>   GSFMIRGKKNFLPPHPLIMGFGILFRLDESSLGFHLNERRVRGEEEGLNDAEQSDPSLAI
>   PDSDSEEELSMETSVDKDITDVPNDRSSVAGTSYEVQSNSLLSISDDKVTNSHNSSVKVN
>   SINNDGLSDSLGIMATSGTSQLEDLIDRALEIGSSTASTKNHGVPPLLGSAGQQDNEEKK
>   VTQREKPYITKAERRKLKKGSDSTEGAPARQEKQSEKNQKAQKQCDEDVNNSKSGGGKVI
>   RGQKGKLKKIKEKYADQDEEERRIRMALLASAGKVEKVDQTIQSEKVDAEPDKGAKATTG
>   PEDASKICYKCKKVGHLSRDCQENSDESLQSTANGGDGHSLTSAGNAANDRDRIVMEEED
>   IHEIGEEEKEKLNDVDYLTGNPLPNDILLYAVPVCGPYNALQSYKYRVKLVPGTVKKGKA
>   AKTAMNLFSHMPEATSREKELMKACTDPELVAAVKGNVKITSAGLTQLKQKQKKSKKSNK
>   AES
>
> Nitab4.5_0000375g0110.1 Tetratricopeptide-like helical, NSF attachment protein, Tetratricopeptide repeat, Malate dehydrogenase, active site, Tetratricopeptide repeat-containing domain
>   MGDQIARGEEFEKKAEKKLSGWGLFGSKHDDAADLFDKAANCFKLAKSWDQAGAVYVKVA
>   NCYLKLDSKHEAAGAYANAAHCYKKTNTREAISCLEQAVHMFLDIGRLNMSARYYKEIAE
>   LYEQEQNLEQAIIYYEKAADLFQSEDVTTSANQCKQKIAQFSAELEKYQRAIEIFEEIAR
>   HSVNNNLLKYGVRGHLLNAGICQLCKGDVVAINNALERYQELDPTFSGTRECKLLVDLAA
>   AIDEEDVAKFTGSVKEYDSMTKLDALRTTLLLRVKEALKAKELEEDDLT
>
> Nitab4.5_0000062g0530.1 DNA polymerase, palm domain, DNA-directed DNA polymerase, family B, conserved site, DNA-directed DNA polymerase, family B, multifunctional domain, DNA-directed DNA polymerase, family B
>   MARVTGVPISFLLARGQSIKVLSQLLRKARQRNLVIPNVKQAGSEQGTYEGATVLEARAG
>   FYEKPIATLDFASLYPSIMMAYNLCYCTLVTPEEFHKLNLCEVDVNKTPSGEMFVKSDLQ
>   KGILPEILEELLAARKRAKADLKEAKDPLVKAVLDGRQLALKISANSVYGFTGATVGQLP
>   CLEISSSVTSYGRQMIEKTKKLVEDKFTVLKGYEHNAEVIYGDTDSVMVQFGVPTVEEAM
>   KLGREAADHISETFIKPLRLEFEKIYYPYLLISKKRYAGLLWTNPDKHDKMDAKGELLAT
>
> Nitab4.5_0005502g0010.1 CDC6, C-terminal domain, P-loop containing nucleoside triphosphate hydrolase, Cell division protein Cdc6/18, Winged helix-turn-helix DNA-binding domain
>   MPTIPVRRSPRISGGSKVAGQTVSRNEIGVSTPSKRKIRSDSTTEDNVVTSTLTPSPMEI
>   SPCKWKSPRRCVNDSPKSPLNANRGDKTINLSKSPVKRRLSESFLEKPIWNPRDMEQLNA
>   VKEALHVSRAPSNLVCRQVEQNRVLEFCKQAVKIEKAGSLYVCGCPGTGKSLSMEKVKEV
>   LVNWADESGFQAPDILSVNCTSLSNTSDIFGKMLDKIQPRRKLNCSTAPLQYLQKMFSEK
>   QQPAGTKMLLIVADELDYLITKDKVVLHELFMLTTSPFSRFILIGIANAIDLADRFLPKL
>   QSMNCEYFPSCKPAVITFCAYSKDQIISILQQRFEKVASASGDMRKALWVCRLVNIAARL
>   ADHSLTKSAIEMLEAEIRDSISSLDLPSLHGRVSYQHRDGACDKSPIHESNVVRVDHVAI
>   ALSKAYRSPVVDTIQSLPQHQQIILCSAVKLFRGKKKDATIGELNISYLDVCKSTLIPPV
>   GIMELSSMCRVLGDQGILKVGKAREEKLSRVTLKVDEADITFALQA
>
> Nitab4.5_0005502g0020.1 
>   MVIEEQCDDEGVQPYIEQLMDGQNYSQAQTHDGQSNDFNNSADTEIQQNDDSGKTIDVQI
>   NSRNQFIGKEGRKLASFLGIVARTPELTPLQCKKWD
>
> Nitab4.5_0005502g0030.1 
>   MINERLRNNSERLNDHPPQSVAWEGDVYSQVLKNKKSGYVRGNIDLEDSSNEVKRLEQKV
>   IELTKLNGKQNEEMSSMKPELLWMRKVMCKIAPNELYMSQNINEISIGQVTQIQKFKTFV
>   LKH
>
> Nitab4.5_0005502g0040.1 Ribosomal protein L10/acidic P0, Ribosomal protein L10/L12
>   MAVKVTKAEKKVNYDKKLCKLLDTYQQILIVGADNVGSNQLQMIRKGLRGDSIVLMGKNT
>   MMKRSIRIHAEKTGNNAFLALIPCLVGNVGLIFTRGDLKEVSDEVSKYKVGAPARVGLVA
>   PIDVVVPPGNTGLDPSQTSFFQVLNIPTKINKGTVEITIPVEIIKKGEKVGSSESALLSK
>   LGIKPFSYGLIVQFVYDSGSVFSPEVLDLTEDDLIAKFAAGLSNVVGLSMLLSYPTLAAI
>   PHMFINGYKNVLSFAIATEYSFPQAEKVKEYLKDPSKFATAIAAPVATKPAVKPATAKEE
>   KKEEPAEEDDDDFVGGLFD

I wanted to print out the description lines (lines starting with >NitabXXXX) and the following amino acid sequences (the capitalized letters) in File B if the gene IDs (Nitab4.5_xxxxx) were found in File A.(In file B, the amino acid sequences were separated in multiple lines)

Here is the code I have come up with so far

```
while IFS= read -r Gene_ID; do sed -n '/$Gene_ID/,/>Nitab4.5/p' File B | sed '$d'; done < File A
```

The code worked with a specified Gene ID and no loop. But I was not able to get it to work after adding the loop. I am new to Linux and sed. Hope someone could point out the mistake and help me correct the code. Thank you!!

Comment: According to your explanation, the description lines should start with `>Nitab` but the provided FileB does not contain the character `>` at the start of the line. Which is corrrect? Besides I can find no matches in the `NitabXXXX` strings between FileA and FileB.

Comment: The description lines start with ">" symbol in my File B, I copied and pasted part of the File B into the question, I guess that is why there was no matching terms found. And I am not sure why the ">" symbol did not show up in the question. I re-edited the question, now File B has terms matching the first and third lines in File A. Thanks for your help! Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: In File B, each gene is on one line, is that correct?

Comment: In File B, the description line (starting with Nitab4.5) of each gene is on one line. However, the following amino acid sequences exist in multiple and varying lines for different genes.

Comment: @jing Because of `>` in front of the lines they are incorrectly rendered. Please add 4 spaces in front of the lines and check the formatting then. [formatting editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing, but could it be that this simple command is what you're looking for?

```
grep -f FILE_A -A 1 FILE_B
```

The options do the following:

> **-f FILE**
>          Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.
>      **-A NUM**
>          Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines.  Places a line containing a group separator (described under --group-separator) between contiguous groups of matches.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried the code, it worked partially. The problems were 1) the amino acid sequences (capitalized letters) exist in multiple and varying lines, 2) the code printed out the description line plus the following one line of amino acid sequence matched to the last line in File A.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's try to print the third entry in `FileB`. (I am calling it `FileB` instead of `File B` because spaces in file names are big headaches.)

```
sed -n '/Nitab4.5_0000062g0530.1/,/>Nitab4.5/p' FileB
>Nitab4.5_0000062g0530.1 DNA polymerase, palm domain, DNA-directed DNA polymerase, family B, conserved site, DNA-directed DNA polymerase, family B, multifunctional domain, DNA-directed DNA polymerase, family B
MARVTGVPISFLLARGQSIKVLSQLLRKARQRNLVIPNVKQAGSEQGTYEGATVLEARAG
FYEKPIATLDFASLYPSIMMAYNLCYCTLVTPEEFHKLNLCEVDVNKTPSGEMFVKSDLQ
KGILPEILEELLAARKRAKADLKEAKDPLVKAVLDGRQLALKISANSVYGFTGATVGQLP
CLEISSSVTSYGRQMIEKTKKLVEDKFTVLKGYEHNAEVIYGDTDSVMVQFGVPTVEEAM
KLGREAADHISETFIKPLRLEFEKIYYPYLLISKKRYAGLLWTNPDKHDKMDAKGELLAT

>Nitab4.5_0005502g0010.1 CDC6, C-terminal domain, P-loop containing nucleoside triphosphate hydrolase, Cell division protein Cdc6/18, Winged helix-turn-helix DNA-binding domain
```

It picked up the first line of the next entry. So instead of terminating at ">Nitab4.5", let's terminate at the empty line:

```
sed -n '/Nitab4.5_0000062g0530.1/,/^$/p' FileB
>Nitab4.5_0000062g0530.1 DNA polymerase, palm domain, DNA-directed DNA polymerase, family B, conserved site, DNA-directed DNA polymerase, family B, multifunctional domain, DNA-directed DNA polymerase, family B
MARVTGVPISFLLARGQSIKVLSQLLRKARQRNLVIPNVKQAGSEQGTYEGATVLEARAG
FYEKPIATLDFASLYPSIMMAYNLCYCTLVTPEEFHKLNLCEVDVNKTPSGEMFVKSDLQ
KGILPEILEELLAARKRAKADLKEAKDPLVKAVLDGRQLALKISANSVYGFTGATVGQLP
CLEISSSVTSYGRQMIEKTKKLVEDKFTVLKGYEHNAEVIYGDTDSVMVQFGVPTVEEAM
KLGREAADHISETFIKPLRLEFEKIYYPYLLISKKRYAGLLWTNPDKHDKMDAKGELLAT
```

Now to do it with a variable:

```
line=Nitab4.5_0000062g0530.1; sed -n '/$line/,/^$/p' FileB
```

We get nothing, because the shell passed `$line` to sed, and sed has its own ideas about what that means. To get the shell to expand the variable before passing it to sed, we must use double quotes:

```
line=Nitab4.5_0000062g0530.1; sed -n "/$line/,/^$/p" FileB
>Nitab4.5_0000062g0530.1 DNA polymerase, palm domain, DNA-directed DNA polymerase, family B, conserved site, DNA-directed DNA polymerase, family B, multifunctional domain, DNA-directed DNA polymerase, family B
MARVTGVPISFLLARGQSIKVLSQLLRKARQRNLVIPNVKQAGSEQGTYEGATVLEARAG
FYEKPIATLDFASLYPSIMMAYNLCYCTLVTPEEFHKLNLCEVDVNKTPSGEMFVKSDLQ
KGILPEILEELLAARKRAKADLKEAKDPLVKAVLDGRQLALKISANSVYGFTGATVGQLP
CLEISSSVTSYGRQMIEKTKKLVEDKFTVLKGYEHNAEVIYGDTDSVMVQFGVPTVEEAM
KLGREAADHISETFIKPLRLEFEKIYYPYLLISKKRYAGLLWTNPDKHDKMDAKGELLAT
```

If this is satisfactory, we can start on the loop. Always start with something simple:

```
while read line; do echo $line; done < FileA
Nitab4.5_0000062g0520.1

Nitab4.5_0000436g0070.1

Nitab4.5_0000375g0110.1
```

Those empty lines are a pain, so let's remove them. We can do that several ways, but since we're using sed anyway, let's use sed:

```
sed '/^$/d' FileA | while read line; do echo $line; done
Nitab4.5_0000062g0520.1
Nitab4.5_0000436g0070.1
Nitab4.5_0000375g0110.1
```

Now we put it all together:

```
sed '/^$/d' FileA | while read line; do sed -n "/$line/,/^$/p" FileB; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for updating your input file. 
If `awk` is your option, would you please try the following:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {RS=ORS="\n\n"; FS="\n"}
    NR==FNR {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) nitab[$i]
        next
    }
    {
        if (match($1, /^>[^[:blank:]]+/)) {
            str = substr($1, 0, RLENGTH)
            if (str in nitab) print
        }
    }
' FileA FileB
```

Output:

```
>Nitab4.5_0000062g0520.1 Zinc finger, CCHC-type, Fibronectin-binding A, N-terminal, Domain of unknown function DUF814, Protein of unknown function DUF3441
MVKVRMNTADVAAEVKCLRRLIGMRCSNVYDLSPKTYVFKLMNSSGVTESGESEKVLLLM
ESGVRLHTTDYLRDKSNTPSGFTLKLRKHIRTRRLEDVRQLGYDRIVLFQFGLGANAHYV
ILELYAQGNILLTDSDFMVMTLLRSHRDDDKGLAIMSRHRYPVEICRVFKRTTTEKLQAA
LMSSAETDKNEGVEDNEQGNDGSDALQQKQGNRKNIKATDSTKKMIDGVRAKSPTLKVVL
GEALGYGPALSEHIILDAGLVPNAKIGKGFELEGEMLHSLIEAVKQFEDWLEDVILGEKV
PEGYILMQQKALSKKDSSMCNNGASEKMYDEFCPLLLNQFKSRDFMKFEAFNAALDEFYS
KIESQRSEQQQKAKESTAMQKLNKIRTDQENRVVTLKQEVEHCIKTAELIEYNLEDVDAA
ILAVRVALANGMSWEDLARMVKEEKRSGNPVAGLIDKLHLERNCMTLLLSNNLDEMDDDE
KTQPVDKVEVDLALSAHANARRWYEMKKRQESKQEKTVTAHEKAFKAAERKTRLQLSQEK
TVAVISHMRKVHWFEKFNWFVSSENYLVISGRDAQQNEMIVKRYMSKGDLYVHAELHGAS
STVIKNHKPEMPIPPLTLNQAGCFTVCQSQAWDSKIVTSAWWVYPNQVSKTAPTGEYLTV
GSFMIRGKKNFLPPHPLIMGFGILFRLDESSLGFHLNERRVRGEEEGLNDAEQSDPSLAI
PDSDSEEELSMETSVDKDITDVPNDRSSVAGTSYEVQSNSLLSISDDKVTNSHNSSVKVN
SINNDGLSDSLGIMATSGTSQLEDLIDRALEIGSSTASTKNHGVPPLLGSAGQQDNEEKK
VTQREKPYITKAERRKLKKGSDSTEGAPARQEKQSEKNQKAQKQCDEDVNNSKSGGGKVI
RGQKGKLKKIKEKYADQDEEERRIRMALLASAGKVEKVDQTIQSEKVDAEPDKGAKATTG
PEDASKICYKCKKVGHLSRDCQENSDESLQSTANGGDGHSLTSAGNAANDRDRIVMEEED
IHEIGEEEKEKLNDVDYLTGNPLPNDILLYAVPVCGPYNALQSYKYRVKLVPGTVKKGKA
AKTAMNLFSHMPEATSREKELMKACTDPELVAAVKGNVKITSAGLTQLKQKQKKSKKSNK
AES

>Nitab4.5_0000375g0110.1 Tetratricopeptide-like helical, NSF attachment protein, Tetratricopeptide repeat, Malate dehydrogenase, active site, Tetratricopepti
de repeat-containing domain
MGDQIARGEEFEKKAEKKLSGWGLFGSKHDDAADLFDKAANCFKLAKSWDQAGAVYVKVA
NCYLKLDSKHEAAGAYANAAHCYKKTNTREAISCLEQAVHMFLDIGRLNMSARYYKEIAE
LYEQEQNLEQAIIYYEKAADLFQSEDVTTSANQCKQKIAQFSAELEKYQRAIEIFEEIAR
HSVNNNLLKYGVRGHLLNAGICQLCKGDVVAINNALERYQELDPTFSGTRECKLLVDLAA
AIDEEDVAKFTGSVKEYDSMTKLDALRTTLLLRVKEALKAKELEEDDLT
```

**[Explanations]**

- The `BEGIN` block assigns the input/output record reparators to double newlines and the field
  separator to a newline. It enables to handle the paragraph (a group of the description line and
  the amino acid lines) as a record.
- The condition `FR==FNR` returns TRUE while reading the 1st file in the argument list (= FileA) only.
  The idiom is useful to switch the procedure depending on the input files.
- The loop `for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) nitab[$i]` stores each line of FileA in an array `nitab`.
- The next statement `match($1, /^>[^[:blank:]]+/)` extracts the `>NitabXXX`
  substring of a recored in FileB which corresponds to the lines of FileA.
- Then the variable `str` is assigned to the substring.
- If `str` matches any entries of the array `nitab`, then print the record.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciated it!